# How can I add class to second td if the first one contains some word?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I add class to second td if the first one contains word ZERO?

```
$('td:nth-child(1):contains("ZERO")').closest('td:nth-child(2)').addClass('intro').removeClass('part-pakiet');
```

Comment: have you `.next()`.

Answer (score 7):

Use an [adjacent sibling combinator](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#adjacent-sibling-combinators) (`+`):

```
$("td:nth-child(1):contains(ZERO) + td").addClass('intro').removeClass('part-pakiet');
```

Example:

```js
$("td:nth-child(1):contains(ZERO) + td").addClass('intro').removeClass('part-pakiet');
```

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
td, td {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
}
.intro {
  color: green;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>first cell - no match</td>
      <td>second cell</td>
      <td>third cell with ZERO</td>
      <td>...to prove to ourselves this doesn't match</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>first cell - ZERO</td>
      <td>second cell</td>
      <td>third cell with ZERO</td>
      <td>...to prove to ourselves this doesn't match</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>first cell - no match</td>
      <td>second cell</td>
      <td>third cell with ZERO</td>
      <td>...to prove to ourselves this doesn't match</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>first cell - ZERO</td>
      <td>second cell</td>
      <td>third cell with ZERO</td>
      <td>...to prove to ourselves this doesn't match</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: This is nice but for me personally using `next` is more readable

Comment: @ZoltánTamási: I guess it depends on your CSS level. This is very readable to someone with solid CSS selectors knowledge. `next` is also a perfectly good solution, of course.

Comment: I treat myself quite good at CSS, however, I always had problems remembering the *direction* of the adjacent sibling operator :)

Comment: @ZoltánTamási: :-) It's the same as the direction of all the other combinators (such as the descendant combinator, e.g. `div span`), if that helps.

Answer (score 4):

In your sample, you use `closest` incorrectly. Closest here refers to the closest ancestor element matching the selector (or the current element if it matches the selector). So in this case you have to get the closest `tr`, and then its second `td`. For the record, here is a working code using `closest`.

```
$('td:nth-child(1):contains("ZERO")').closest('tr').find('td:nth-child(2)').addClass('intro').removeClass('part-pakiet');
```

However, in this scenario you don't need to use `closest`, because there is a simpler way using `next` selector.

```
$('td:nth-child(1):contains("ZERO")').next().addClass('intro').removeClass('part-pakiet');
```

Comment: I have one (ridiculously minor) quibble; "*[closest] here refers to the closest* parent..."; [`closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) *always* refers to the closest ancestor element (or the current element if it matches the selector), and never anything else.

Comment: @DavidThomas thanks, actually I was seeking for the word *ancestor* which didn't come to my mind (my english is not perfect).

Comment: I don't know your mother-tongue, Zoltán, but I suspect you speak far, *far* better English than I speak your own first language. It wasn't so much the ancestor/parent difference that bothered me, it was the implication that in some cases `closest()` might not look towards the parents/ancestors. As I said: 'ridiculously minor quibble' :)

Comment: Just for the sake of completeness, it's hungarian :)

Answer (score 0):

More literal approach if the text is definitely equal to that word. Other wise use the :contains pseudo:

```js
var tableElement = $('.table td:first-child'),
    wordToCheck  = 'ZERO';

if (tableElement.text() === wordToCheck) {
  tableElement.next().addClass('intro').removeClass('part-pakiet');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>ZERO</td>
            <td class="part-pakiet"></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `filter()` function for this:

```
$('td').filter(function(){
    return ~$(this).prev('td').text().indexOf('ZERO'); // check if prev td contains 'ZERO' text
}).addClass('intro').removeClass('part-pakiet');
```